# LinkedListMultimap or MultiMap sequence

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, dictionary, multimap

I have the following multiMap:

```
1st: [3=>[4,5]]
2nd: [2=>[3]]
3rd: [0=>[2]]
4th: [5=>[1]]
5th: [4=>[1]]
```

I would like to get the sequence out of it such as:

```
0->2->3->[4,5]->1
```

Is it possible?

This is what I have tried, but doesn't seem to work correctly:

```
// the starting point is given from the start.

Collection<String> col = new HashSet<String>();
col.add("0");
buildPath2(myMultimap, col, result2);

static void buildPath2(Multimap<String, String> path, Collection<String> token, List<Collection<String>> result2) {
    if (token != null) {
        result2.add(token);
        Collection<String> c = null;
        for (String elem: token){
           c = path.get(elem);
        }
        buildPath2(path, c, result2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible.  What is your question?

Comment: my question is to how to get this sequence 0->2->3->[4,5]->1?

Comment: It is not always possible if you want to start with `0`. Indeed, you could have some association like `5=>[3,0,2]`.

Comment: What if 3=>[4,5] | 4=>[1] | [5=>2] ?

Comment: starting point is already given at the start.

Comment: This is missing in the problem statement. And if your multimap contains `5=>[3,0,2]`, your algorithm can fail to find the cycle when it starts with `0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got two basic problems that you'll need to resolve.

1. Your program doesn't seem to output anything.  Somewhere in there, you'll want to output `result2` somehow.
2. After your `for` loop, `c` will be whatever you get from looking up the last element of `token` in the map.  You probably wanted it to be a `Set` containing what you get from looking up all the elements of `token` in the map.

To deal with issue 2, you should probably change

```
Collection<String> c = null;
for (String elem: token){
   c = path.get(elem);
}
```

to

```
Collection<String> c = new HashSet<>();
for (String elem : token) {
    c.addAll(path.get(elem));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Choose the starting index
Assign starting index to current index
do
  output path[current index]
  current index= path[current index][some index°]
while current index != starting index
```

°Depending on your exact policy. Will normally be the last index in the list.